# Running V8 Javascript Engine Standalone

Tags: javascript, v8

I want to run a Javascript console on top of V8. How do I do this?

Answer (score 121, accepted):

V8 is easy to build and does not come with the Java VM overhead from Mozilla's standalone Javascript interpreter. Luckily, V8 ships with code for building a console. Here is how to build this:

```
$> svn co http://v8.googlecode.com/svn/trunk v8-trunk
...
$> cd v8-trunk
$> scons
$> g++ ./samples/shell.cc -o v8-shell -I include libv8.a
```

Now, we have a standalone binary called `v8-shell`.

Running the console:

```
$> ./v8-shell 
V8 version 2.0.2
> var x = 10;
> x
10
> function foo(x) { return x * x; }
> foo
function foo(x) { return x * x; }
> quit()
```

Executing Javascript from the command line:

```
$> ./v8-shell -e 'print("10*10 = " + 10*10)'
10*10 = 100
```

Many more features are documented in the help:

```
$> ./v8-shell --help
Usage:
...
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip and explicit instructions.  I had to add the option `-lpthread` to the `g++` command under ubuntu 10.04.

Comment: scons failed for me on Ubuntu, but running sudo apt-get install libc6-dev-i386 solved that.

Comment: and if your on x86_64 do a: 'scons arch=x64' until its fixed in trunk
http://code.google.com/p/v8/issues/detail?id=429#c1

Comment: Or pass the -arch i386 to g++.

Comment: Please note that this v8-shell is intended to be a toy example. The "real" v8 shell is called `d8`. See my answer for more info.

Comment: `$> g++ ./samples/shell.cc -o -lpthread v8-shell -I include libv8.a ` use above if you are using ubuntu 10.04..enjoy!!!

Comment: I got `$ scons

scons: *** No SConstruct file found.
File "/usr/local/Cellar/scons/2.3.4/libexec/scons-local/SCons/Script/Main.py", line 920, in _main` when doing this. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The method for fetching the source code seems changed. See [here](https://github.com/v8/v8/wiki/Building%20from%20Source).

Answer (score 61):

To build the developer console, rather than the example 'shell' toy application, copy-paste the below commands to your terminal.

```
sudo apt-get install subversion scons libreadline-dev
svn co http://v8.googlecode.com/svn/trunk v8
cd v8/
scons console=readline d8
```

These instruction will work for Ubuntu/Debian with a "generic" kernel. For other distributions, you will need to replace the apt-get command with whatever package tool you have available. On 64-bit systems you may need to add `arch=x64`. The `console=readline` option enables the [readline](http://www.gnu.org/s/readline/) system, to make it feel a bit more like a standard shell.

More complete documentation here:
http://code.google.com/apis/v8/build.html

---

Note:

[image]

See also: [Building v8 with GYP](http://code.google.com/p/v8/wiki/BuildingWithGYP)

Comment: I had to add `arch=x64` to build on 64bit ubuntu.

Comment: @Hugh: It enables the readline system; this is what allows you to use the up arrow to get the previous command, among other niceties.

Comment: Once building has finished, run the shell by entering `./d8`.

Comment: on ubunt 12.04: fatal error: readline/readline.h: No such file or directory - any ideas?

Answer (score 44):

How about running V8 Javascript via command line using [node.js](http://nodejs.org/)?

node.js uses v8 as it's engine and adds a lot of functionality on top of it.

---

For example on Mac OSX if you have [Homebrew](http://nodejs.org/) installed, simply issue:

```
    $ brew install node
    $ node
    >
```

Comment: IMHO node.js is the new defacto standard when it comes to JavaScript consoles.  It uses v8, and is probably the best option to use for this.

Answer (score 24):

On Mac OS X be sure to have [`brew`](https://brew.sh) installed. Then just run the command `(sudo) brew install v8`, depending on your machine this may take some time. To start the V8 console, just run `v8` - Voilà!

**Tip:** To quit the console, just run `quit()` and don't forget the parentheses!

Comment: Or just press `Ctrl-D` to quit :)

Comment: Or `Ctrl-C` to kill it

Comment: You can build v8 by itself and it's simple enough, using brew is just way too cumbersome.

Comment: How is 'brew install v8' cumbersome?

Answer (score 6):

I think this might have changed. I [read the manual](https://developers.google.com/v8/build) and build v8 like this:

```
moose@pc08$ svn co http://v8.googlecode.com/svn/trunk v8-trunk
moose@pc08$ cd v8-trunk
moose@pc08$ make dependencies
moose@pc08$ make ia32.release
```

added `export PATH=${PATH}:/home/moose/Downloads/v8-trunk/out/ia32.release` to my .bashrc

```
moose@pc08 ~ $ source ~/.bashrc
moose@pc08 ~ $ d8 A_tic_tac_toe_Tomek.js < A-small-practice.in
```

(With javascript from [aditsu](http://www.go-hero.net/jam/13/name/aditsu) and A-small-practice.in from Google Code Jam)

Comment: A page full of responses and yours, the least regarded, contains the final advice I needed.

Answer (score 5):

After following the build instructions ([Google's V8 Build Docs](https://developers.google.com/v8/build)) for your system;

```
[v8 directory]$ cd out/native
[v8 directory]$ ./shell (sample shell)
[v8 directory]$ ./d8 (console: dumb)
```

I created an alias in my .bash_profile to facilitate invocation of the shell.

```
alias v8='/Volumes/Dev/GitHub/v8/out/native/shell'
```

Typing v8 at the CLI (in a new Terminal or shell -- to reload your bash profile) yields the v8 shell. JavaScript at the command prompt! :)

Answer (score 4):

If you use ArchLinux, you can use `pacman -S v8` to install it.
Then use `d8` to start it in your shell.
Enjoy it.

Comment: That appears to be on the AUR so cannot be installed with pacman.

Answer (score 4):

In case you would like to run your javascript source code using the *v8* engine or any version of it, you may utilize the [jsvu](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsvu) command-line tool. It is developed and maintained by Google engineers and, besides, it offers the feature of installing other javascript engines apart from *v8*, such as *spidermonkey*, *chakracore*, *javascriptcore*, and *xs*.

Answer (score 2):

If you're planning to embed V8, then by all means build it and play with "d8".

If on the other hand, you do not plan to extend V8 or treat it as optional,
then just use Node.JS.  Don't bother with pure V8.

Node.js has truly rich I/O, extensions, libraries (like Perl CPAN, Python Eggs, Ruby Gems), and community.

Comment: You don't need to use node.js, it's just a wrapper and extra dependency.

Answer (score 0):

#### If you are on Windows:

1. Install MSYS2
2. Open MSYS2 terminal from start menu.
3. Install your compiler: `pacman -Syu mingw-w64-i686-toolchain`
4. Install v8: `mingw-w64-i686-v8`
5. Verify that you have `d8` as a new interpreter in your path.
6. If you want to run d8 outside MSYS2, you have to add msys2/mingw/bin to the windows path

###### Test it

7. Navigate to `c:\msys2\home\user\`
8. Create a test.js file

```
console.log('Hello You!');
console.log('Would you tell me your name?');
const name = readline();
console.log('Hello '+name+' !!');
```

9. Run: `d8 test.js`

You can also download binaries from [here](https://packages.msys2.org/package/mingw-w64-i686-v8?repo=mingw32) and unzip with peazip.

Good luck !!