# Is there a way to use Google's v8 JavaScript engine as a standalone interpreter?

Tags: javascript, v8

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Running V8 Javascript Engine Standalone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1802478/running-v8-javascript-engine-standalone)

I want to try a standalone JavaScript interpreter, rather than executing in Firefox all the time. I did find spidermonkey by googling, which could be installed on ubuntu, but is there a way to use Google's v8 as a standalone interpreter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**edit**: misread your question. Sorry xD, take a look at this post instead: [Running V8 Javascript Engine Standalone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1802478/running-v8-javascript-engine-standalone)

There you'll find instructions on how to build the interpreter.

Comment: Yeah, I know, I realized my answer had nothing to do with the question right after clicking send =P edited it a second later.

Comment: Your link is to an answer about Python.

Comment: LOL. Fixed. I don't know where my head is. Thanks for spotting that, I would've walked away thinking I might've helped someone.

Comment: Well i finally installed and it worked .. but there are many things that work in the browser but not in this standalone interpreter  For example , the alert(" test") function , it works fine in browser , but not in this standalone one .. am i missing on something here ?

Answer (score 5):

Yup yup yup! You can download the V8 shell from Google and run it on its own:

http://code.google.com/apis/v8/build.html

Answer (score 2):

Not only can you run V8 standalone, there is a great project called [node.js](http://nodejs.org/) that adds some very useful libraries.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, v8 can run standalone. http://code.google.com/p/v8/

Detailed instructions for building v8 on Windows: http://code.google.com/p/v8/wiki/BuildingOnWindows

Answer (score 0):

If you install node.js it gives you command line access to V8 (sans DOM)

**Edit:** [Node ppa](http://wiki.mediatemple.net/w/Installing_Node.js_on_Ubuntu)