# Pass command-line arguments to script in V8 Javascript shell

Tags: javascript, v8, jslint

I'm trying to run JSLint via V8.

- I downloaded and built the V8 shell using [these instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1802478/running-v8-javascript-engine-standalone).
- The interactive shell `d8` works, and passing a file to it executes that file.

Now I want to execute `jslint.js` and pass the name of the file to parse to it. I have tried

```
d8 jslint.js myfile.js
d8 jslint.js < myfile.js
d8 jslint.js -- myfile.js
```

No doubt the trouble lines in the end of jslint.js which uses the Rhino `readline()` function to get the command-line arguments. Has anyone modified this script to work in V8 or is there a generic way to have V8 pass arguments to it?

**Update:** Steve's answer reminded me that I did find a way to [compile JSLint into an executable](https://github.com/geekq/jslint-v8) much as Steve did, but I was hoping for something that was a little more portable for the other developers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The d8 shell allows you to pass arguments on the command line by preceding them by '--'.
I.e., in your case:

```
  d8 jslint.js -- myfile.js
```

Everthing after '--' will be read as verbatim strings, so all other flags must go before that.
The command line arguments will be available to scripts as a global variable called "arguments" holding an array of strings.

(Instead of '--' you can use the synonymous '--js-arguments').

Comment: This was [broken](http://code.google.com/p/v8/issues/detail?id=1477) for a while but is fixed again.

Answer (score 2):

You could possibly have a look at my attempt to run JSLint using v8 at http://blog.stevenreid.co.uk/2011/06/27/jslint-command-line-tool-powered-by-v8/.

The command line application compiles JSLint directly into the binary. All JSlint options are supported. Multiple source files can be linted as well as input from stdin.

Comment: I was unable to build FOX. The `make` command dies saying it cannot find `-lXext`, `-lGL`, and `-lGLU`. Any ideas?

Comment: Even though the build failed, you should hopefully have the 'reswrap' executable now. That's all that is needed.

Comment: Okay, now it's complaining that v8preparser.a is incompatible. This is probably because I am running 64-bit and had to specify `--arch=x64` when building v8. Is there a way to pass that to your scons script? The same argument is kicked out by scons.

Comment: Sorry no, the scons script supports 32-bit only atm.

Comment: Okay no worries. Thanks for the effort.